# How to balance two Forex crosses correctly to do a linear regression?

Tags: r, fx, regression

I have two cross and an account in EUR:

1. EUR/USD
2. GBP/USD

I would like to do a balanced linear regression using R. With "balanced" I mean that I would like to normalize it by calculating the difference in pips from the previous day and the current, and then multiply by the respective (middle) pip value.

I do a simple example:

The series are:

**EUR/USD**
1.3000
1.3050
1.3060

**GBP/USD**
1.6000
1.6050
1.6060

---

The differences are:

---

**EUR/USD**

1. 50 pips *(1.3000 - 1.3050)*
2. 10 pips *(1.3050 - 1.3060)*

**GBP/USD**

1. 50 pips *(1.6000 - 1.6050)*
2. 10 pips *(1.6050 - 1.6060)*

---

Now, calculate (the values are inventend) the middle pip values:

*(remember that account currency in EUR)*

---

**EUR/USD**

1. **13 €** pip value *(at middle pip: 1.3025)*
2. **13.5 €** pip value *(at middle pip: 1.3055)*

**GBP/USD**

1. **9 €** pip value *(at middle pip: 1.6025)*
2. **8.5 €** pip value *(at middle pip: 1.6055)*

---

Now the normalized series that I studied should be:

---

**EUR/USD**

- 50(pip difference) * 13€ = 650
- 10(pip difference) * 13.5€ = 135

**GBP/USD**

- 50(pip difference) * 9€ = 450
- 10(pip difference) * 8.5€ = 85

---

The normalized series are:

---

**EUR/ USD:** 650, 135

**GBP/USD:** 450, 85

***What do you think of this type of procedure?***
(then I will use those series in the linear regression)

Comment: Hopefully I'm beginning to understand but I wonder: could you also use a return series?

Comment: @Bootvis If I use the returns series I think that the coefficients of the linear regression will be "wrong", I mean, If I use returns instead of the procedure above I could get different returns BUT with the same "move" (the same number of pips)...so when I will look at the coefficients of the linear regression, I can't use the coefficient AS multiplier for lots. No?